# Adding SSL to Heroku site post launch

Tags: ssl, heroku

I have a rails API that I want to deploy on Heroku. $20/month for a SSL site on heroku is a little steep given I am not earning anything out of this app yet. I am after advice and wondering if it is possible to add SSL sometime in the future? This is for a iOS app that I'm writing.

Basically the idea would be that I continue to use https://myapp.heroku.com through their piggyback SSL. Once I get some cash in, I want to transition to using https://www.myapp.com. At this point the API would still need to work for app users who haven't upgraded to a new version of the app that points to the new domain.

Anyone know if this is possible? Would both URLs continue to work? My gut feeling tells me this is not possible. Any advice would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the [custom domain add-on](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) you can have multiple domain names for the same app.

However with SSL I am unsure (as in I have not tested it) if it works.

An option is to have your own httpd server infront, for example apache2 with mod proxy, [which is what I use](http://flurdy.com/docs/herokuplay/play2.html#apache). That way you can use your own ssl certificated and proxy traffic to which ever heroku app you want.

Answer (score 0):

For apps in the US region, you will alway retain the myapp.herokuapp.com domain (as long as you don't rename the app), and SSL will keep working on that domain name even after you add custom domains and add SSL to those custom domains.

For EU apps, the myapp.herokuapp.com host stops working if you add an SSL endpoint.